# Windows 10 Host, VM Workstation Player 14, Guest Windows server 2016 (trial version) - install error

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player, windows-10-preview

VMWorkstation Player 14.1.2 build-8497320
Windows 10 Preview [Version 10.0.17704.1000]

I tried to install the trial version of Windows 2016 server without a licence key.
VMWare detected it was Windows 2016 Server.
It started the Windows installation screens.
I got the error message
“Windows cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms. Make sure the installation sources are valid and restart the installation.”

On previous versions of Windows server I had not needed a licence key for evaluation versions.

Comment: What is Windows Server 2016 build? was it downloaded from the [evaluation center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016/)?

Comment: Hi A.Newgate, downloaded from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016
 I downloaded the .iso and installed on VMWARE Workstation Player

Answer (score 2):

I tried again using a licence key and that changed the error message.

No Windows installation screens yet.
I got to the "Press any key to boot" message within VMWare.
unsuccessful.
-EFI Network
STart PXE over IPv4

I then shut down my virtual machine and (based on suggestions I'd read earlier) I deleted my (virtual) floppy drive from the VM hardware.

I then restarted my machine and Windows installed normally on my VM.

I hope this saves somebody some time.

=====================

**Aug 2018**

Forget about the easy install that works well e.g. for Ubuntu.
We will be using the CD ROM via the BIOS to launch Windows install.

1 Creating a new machine
Work your way through the New Virtual Machine wizard,
Select "I will install the operating system later"

Guest OS select Microsoft Windows

Name of virtual machine - give it a name

Specify disk capacity - complete as required

Customise hardware
Select the CD/DVD
Device status connected at power on - ticked
Use ISO image file (browse to location of Windows 2016 ISO image)

Finish the wizard

The image is now switched off

2 We will now power on the machine.
Then wait for the BIOS/Firmware (Boot Manager) to startup

To save a few seconds you may find VM, Power menu, Power on to Firmware

Within the Boot Manager select the CD Rom drive

The screen will say press any key

The in  a few seconds the Windows logo will display on a black screen and Windows will start the install